Hedging an Equity Index Open Fixing
How would a delta-1 desk hedge a TRS on a major equity index (assume SPX/NDX/SX5E/DAX/HSI/NKY) that is fixed vs the cash open?
I understand that the open is technically a mix of live and stale prices therefore assume the index open cannot be perfectly replicated using a basket. SOQ prints can deviate materially, trading ETFs and/or futures around the open can often incorporate a supply/demand imbalances.
Given the above, how would a market maker hedge any OTC derivative (assume a TRS for simplicity) that fixes vs. an equity index cash open?

First of all I'm not a market maker so cannot say how a market maker hedges this. But if faced with this my initial idea is that I'd price in either the overnight risk (you hedge towards the close of the previous day, and your price/strike includes the overnight risk) and/or an Asian tail (you hedge shortly after cash open and price that Asian tail in as the strike).

Pricing in anticipated slippage from your hedge and holding some reserve pnl is certainly one way to do it. Outside of this forum, some have discussed both laying off against other internal flow (nice if you have it) or using a combination of over-hedging on the open and using adjusted hedge limits once the opening print has been determined, but neither sound like an elegant approach.
